# PyCharm "Reload from Disk" slow update

Tags: pycharm

I created some files using Ubuntu Terminal and then tried "Reload from Disk" on PyCharm so that PyCharm can see the new files. It took minutes to see the update. But sometimes the updated files are automatically shown in a few minutes without clicking "Reload from Disk". Is there any way to see the file updates in real time on PyCharm?

Comment: Are you doing this using the terminal inside PyCharm? [What terminal did you configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html#application-settings) the IDE to use? Can you include screenshots and some system diagnostic information?

Comment: @bad_coder I am not using PyCharm terminal. I use a usual Ubuntu Terminal. It means I just modify some file outside PyCharm and I want PyCharm to reflect such update of files. I manually click "Reload from Disk" under the folder on PyCharm. It seems this "Reload from Disk" does not work. I did search online and got no useful result.

Comment: Are you sure the terminal flushed the changes and they are committed on disk?

Comment: @bad_coder sure. the file changes were reflected on PyCharm automatically after several minutes.

Comment: Strange, for me external changes are reflected immediately inside the editor... I couldn't find a system setting to configure this, I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer to this question if you post it on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) since the problem seems to be OS specific and you get a specialized user base on the other site.

Answer (score 0):

you can force reload by: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd>